# Error reading To CC and BCC properties

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm trying to extract all my email to an external program (AIMMS). I first store it all in Excel for reading purposes.

I wrote some VBA-code. The **.To** function does not work (gives instant error) when multiple email-addresses are in this field. The same goes for .CC and .BCC.

```
Sub Extract_mail(MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name As String, Subfolder As String)

'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"

Dim folders As Outlook.folders
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim objMItem As MailItem

If Subfolder = "" Then
    Set Folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailBoxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
Else
    Set Folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailBoxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name).folders(Subfolder)
End If

If Folder = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo end_lbl1:
End If

'Rad Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "ID"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "To"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3) = "EmailAddress"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 4) = "Name"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5) = "Subject"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = "Date"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 7) = "Body"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 8) = "Size"

For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = iRow
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).To
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 7) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow + 1, 8) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size

Next iRow

ActiveWorkbook.Save
'ActiveWorkbook.Close

end_lbl1:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that you are looping through your Outlook-email-folder, but there are other items than e-mails in there as well, i.e. "MeetingItem".  There are a couple of items that can reside in such folders, that do not have the .To-property.

So, you need a simple check for MailItems and continue from there:

```
Sub Extract_mail(MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name As String, Optional Subfolder As String)

  'Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders
  Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim iRow As Integer
  Dim olItem As Object

  If Subfolder = "" Then
      Set oFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
  Else
      Set oFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(Subfolder)
  End If

  If oFolder.Name = "" Then
      MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
      Exit Sub
  End If

  iRow = 0

  'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells.Clear
    .Cells(1, 1) = "ID"
    .Cells(1, 2) = "To"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "EmailAddress"
    .Cells(1, 4) = "Name"
    .Cells(1, 5) = "Subject"
    .Cells(1, 6) = "Date"
    .Cells(1, 7) = "Body"
    .Cells(1, 8) = "Size"

    For Each olItem In oFolder.Items
      If TypeOf olItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then  'This is the important bit!
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 1) = iRow
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 2) = olItem.To
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 3) = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 4) = olItem.SenderName
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 5) = olItem.Subject
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 6) = olItem.ReceivedTime
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 7) = olItem.Body
        .Cells(iRow + 2, 8) = olItem.Size
        iRow = iRow + 1
      End If
    Next olItem
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! That was it indeed :) Thanks, also for cleaning up the code! Quick question: after running it, I cannot open it anymore to view the data, everything is grey and I cannot go through the tabs in excel. How do I solve this?

Comment: That is a good question, of which I do not have an answer unfortunately. The code I wrote should not result in such behaviour. If you are nevertheless happy with the answer, can you accept it as the answer? Thx.